# VS Code and Metals: Run 'Build import' to enable code navigation

Tags: visual-studio-code, mill, scala-metals

I have a *Scala*- / *Mill*-Project that I wan't to import into *VSCode*.

The *Metals Doctor* gives me the following warnings:

[image: Metals Doctor image]

Is there something missing in my project?

Here is my *Mill* configuration (`build.sc`):

```
import mill._
import mill.define.Target
import scalalib._

trait MyModule extends ScalaModule {
  def scalaVersion = "2.13.1"

  object version {
    val cats = "2.0.0"
    ..
  }

  object libs {
    val cats = ivy"org.typelevel::cats-core:${version.cats}"
    ..
  }

  object test extends Tests {
    ...
  }

}

object entity extends MyModule {
  override def ivyDeps = {
    Agg(
      libs.cats,
      ..
    )
  }
}

object macros extends MyModule {
..
}
```

Here is the whole project: https://github.com/pme123/zio-examples

The console output shows no warnings, here is the end:

```
...
time: connected to build server in 0.33s
time: imported build in 0.41s
time: indexed workspace in 3.85s
no build target: /Users/mpa/dev/Github/pme123/zio-examples/build.sc
```

Comment: Which version of mill do you use?

Comment: @TobiasRoeser   --mill-version 0.5.1

Comment: I had the same issue on 2.13.1 but if I downgrade to 2.12.8 it works fine. Then I get a warning that in the future 2.12.8 won't be supported and to upgrade to 2.12.10 which also gives me the same error. It may be a bug.

Comment: Since 0.5.1 a lot has happened in BSP support in Mill. Since 0.9.3 it's a core module, and in 0.10.0-M4 it got a major revamp. Have a look at the documentation: https://com-lihaoyi.github.io/mill/mill/Intro_to_Mill.html#_build_server_protocol_bsp

Answer (score 0):

This error/help message is misleading, as it presumes you are using Bloop, in which case re-importing solves the isssue (from experience). When you are using Mill's built-in BSP server, this won't change much.

Mill's recent 0.10.0-M4 release got a major BSP revamp. Also Metals improved it's Mill support. So you should have a better overall experience.

Here is some documentation: https://com-lihaoyi.github.io/mill/mill/Intro_to_Mill.html#_build_server_protocol_bsp